# C++ When outputting vector list, the amount outputted is squared

Tags: c++, system

I am a beginner CS student, who is trying to program a "cashier" system using the numbers from my parents' restaurant.

So far the program can only add the first two appetizers for Table 1, and then print the total with tax on screen.

My issue here is that while the program runs the way I want for now, when I try to "VIEW TOTAL" the items outputted are squared... meaning if I add the item "KIMBAB" once, it will only show one on the outputted list; however, if I add KIMBAB twice, the number of items outputted become 4, if I add 3, it outputs 9 etc.

If I use "JON" as well (item 2 on Appetizer menu), and add KIMBAB, JON then KIMBAB again, the output looks like

KIMBAB

KIMBAB

KIMBAB

JON

JON

JON

KIMBAB

KIMBAB

KIMBAB

Below is the source code for what I have so far, if anyone could help me out that would be fantastic! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

float sum(const vector<float>& x);

// prices
        // appetizers
float kimBab=5.50, jon=7.50, kJon=6.50, sTofu=5.50, wanja=7.50, kgSalad=5.50, edamame=4.00, fVeggies=5.50;
        // mains
float BBB=14.50, BGG=17.50, seaFood=19.50, dakChim=17.50, djGalbi=17.50, soGalbi=19.50;
        // soups
float kimchiC=12.50, dwenjangC=12.50, ygJang=14.50, sdbC=12.50, bjC=14.50;
        // rice and noodles
float japChae=14.50, BBK=10.50, ksBokum=12.50, dopBab=12.50;
        // fusion
float cbggQ=13.50, bggB=13.50, bggBag=13.50, bggW=12.50, bggP=12.50;
        // desserts
float breadP=4.00, vIC=3.00, sjG=3.00, gelato=3.50, butterT=2.50;

// item entry
        // appetizers
string kimBabS="KIMBAB", jonS="JON", kJonS="KIMCHI JON", sTofuS="SEASONED TOFU", wanjaS="WANJA", kgSaladS="KOREAN GREEN SALAD", edamameS="EDAMAME", fVeggiesS="FRESH VEGGIES WITH DIP";
        // mains
string BBBS="BIBIMBAB", BGGS="BULGOGI", seaFoodS="SEAFOOD", dakChimS="DAK-CHIM", djGalbiS="DWEJIGALBI-CHIM", soGalbiS="SOGALBI-DUKBEGI";
        // soups
string kimchiCS="KIMCHI-CHIGYE", dwenjangCS="DWENJANG-CHIGYE", ygJangS="YOUKGYEJANG", sdbCS="SOONDUBU-CHIGYE", bjCS="BIJI-CHIGYE";
        // rice and noodles
string japChaeS="JAPCHAE", BBKS="BIBIMKUKSU", ksBokumS="KUKSUBOKUM", dopBabS="DOPBAB";
        // fusion
string cbggQS="CHICKEN BULGOGI QUESADILLA", bggBS="BULGOGI BURGER", bggBagS="BULGOGI BAGUETTE", bggWS="BULGOGI WRAP", bggPS="BULGOGI PANINI";
        // desserts
string breadPS="BREAD PUDDING", vICS="VANILLA ICE CREAM", sjGS="SUJUNGGWA", gelatoS="GELATO", butterTS="BUTTER TART";
        // attributes
string beef="BEEF", pork="PORK", chicken="CHICKEN", shrimp="SHRIMP", tofu="TOFU";

// variables
string table1="1", table2="2", table3="3", table4="4", table5="5", table6="6", table7="7", table8="8", table9="9", table10="10";
string appySelect="1", mainSelect="2", soupSelect="3", riceNoodleSelect="4", dessertSelect="5";
string appyInput, mainInput, soupInput, riceNoodleInput, fusionInput, dessertInput, attInput, addAnotherInput;
string itemEntry1, itemEntry2, itemEntry3, itemEntry4, itemEntry5, itemEntry6, itemEntry7, itemEntry8, itemEntry9, itemEntry10, itemEntry11, itemEntry12, itemEntry13, itemEntry14, itemEntry15, itemEntry16, itemEntry17, itemEntry18, itemEntry19, itemEntry20;
float itemPrice1, itemPrice2, itemPrice3, itemPrice4, itemPrice5, itemPrice6, itemPrice7, itemPrice8, itemPrice9, itemPrice10, itemPrice11, itemPrice12, itemPrice13, itemPrice14, itemPrice15, itemPrice16, itemPrice17, itemPrice18, itemPrice19, itemPrice20;
float totalpreTax, totalpostTax, addHST, addtaxHST=0.14, totaltaxHST=1.14;
// booleans
bool itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour, itemFive, itemSix, itemSeven, itemEight, itemNine, itemTen, itemEleven, itemTwelve, itemThirteen, itemFourteen, itemFifteen, itemSixteen, itemSeventeen, itemEighteen, itemNineteen, itemTwenty;
// input variables
string tableNumber;
string selectInput;
string itemInput1, itemInput2, itemInput3, itemInput4, itemInput5, itemInput6, itemInput7, itemInput8, itemInput9, itemInput10, itemInput11, itemInput12, itemInput13, itemInput14, itemInput15, itemInput16, itemInput17, itemInput18, itemInput19, itemInput20;
string itemAtt1, itemAtt2, itemAtt3, itemAtt4, itemAtt5, itemAtt6, itemAtt7, itemAtt8, itemAtt9, itemAtt10, itemAtt11, itemAtt12, itemAtt13, itemAtt14, itemAtt15, itemAtt16, itemAtt17, itemAtt18, itemAtt19, itemAtt20;

// MATH FUNCTIONS
void totalposttaxCalc ()
{
    totalpreTax = itemPrice1 + itemPrice2 + itemPrice3 + itemPrice4 + itemPrice5 + itemPrice6 + itemPrice7 + itemPrice8 + itemPrice9 + itemPrice10 + itemPrice11 + itemPrice12 + itemPrice13 + itemPrice14 + itemPrice15 + itemPrice16 + itemPrice17 + itemPrice18 + itemPrice19 + itemPrice20;
    addHST = totalpreTax * addtaxHST;
    totalpostTax = totalpreTax * totaltaxHST;
    cout << string(50, '\n');
    cout << "Total:  " << "$" << totalpreTax << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Tax  :  " << "$" << addHST << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Grand Total:  " << "$" << totalpostTax;
    std::cin.get();
}
// SELECTION FUNCTIONS
void tableSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter table number: ";
        cin >> tableNumber;
    } while ((tableNumber!=table1)&&(tableNumber!=table2)&&(tableNumber!=table3)&&(tableNumber!=table4)&&(tableNumber!=table5)&&(tableNumber!=table6)&&(tableNumber!=table7)&&(tableNumber!=table8)&&(tableNumber!=table9)&&(tableNumber!=table10));
}
void menuSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= MENU =-" << endl;
        cout << "1. Appetizers" << endl;
        cout << "2. Mains" << endl;
        cout << "3. Soups" << endl;
        cout << "4. Rice and Noodles" << endl;
        cout << "5. Fusion" << endl;
        cout << "6. Desserts" << endl;
        cout << "7. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "8. SEE COMPLETE ORDER." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selectInput;
    } while ((selectInput!="1")&&(selectInput!="2")&&(selectInput!="3")&&(selectInput!="4")&&(selectInput!="5")&&(selectInput!="6")&&(selectInput!="7")&&(selectInput!="8"));
}
void appySelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= APPETIZERS =- " << endl;
        cout << "1. " << kimBabS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << jonS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << kJonS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << sTofuS << endl;
        cout << "5. " << wanjaS << endl;
        cout << "6. " << kgSaladS << endl;
        cout << "7. " << edamameS << endl;
        cout << "8. " << fVeggiesS << endl;
        cout << "9. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> appyInput;
        } while ((appyInput!="1")&&(appyInput!="2")&&(appyInput!="3")&&(appyInput!="4")&&(appyInput!="5")&&(appyInput!="6")&&(appyInput!="7")&&(appyInput!="8")&&(appyInput!="9"));
}
void mainSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= MAINS =-" << endl;
        cout << "1. " << BBBS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << BGGS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << seaFoodS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << dakChimS << endl;
        cout << "5. " << djGalbiS << endl;
        cout << "6. " << soGalbiS << endl;
        cout << "7. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> mainSelect;
    } while ((mainSelect!="1")&&(mainSelect!="2")&&(mainSelect!="3")&&(mainSelect!="4")&&(mainSelect!="5")&&(mainSelect!="6")&&(mainSelect!="7"));
}
void soupSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= SOUPS =- " << endl;
        cout << "1. " << kimchiCS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << dwenjangCS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << ygJangS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << sdbCS << endl;
        cout << "5. " << bjCS << endl;
        cout << "6. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> soupInput;
    } while ((soupInput!="1")&&(soupInput!="2")&&(soupInput!="3")&&(soupInput!="4")&&(soupInput!="5")&&(soupInput!="6"));
}
void riceNoodleSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= RICE AND NOODLES =- " << endl;
        cout << "1. " << japChaeS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << BBKS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << ksBokumS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << dopBabS << endl;
        cout << "5. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> riceNoodleInput;
    } while ((riceNoodleInput!="1")&&(riceNoodleInput!="2")&&(riceNoodleInput!="3")&&(riceNoodleInput!="4")&&(riceNoodleInput!="5"));
}
void fusionSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= FUSION =- " << endl;
        cout << "1. " << cbggQS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << bggBS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << bggBagS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << bggWS << endl;
        cout << "5. " << bggPS << endl;
        cout << "6. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> fusionInput;
        } while ((fusionInput!="1")&&(fusionInput!="2")&&(fusionInput!="3")&&(fusionInput!="4")&&(fusionInput!="5")&&(fusionInput!="6"));
}
void dessertSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= DESSERTS =- " << endl;
        cout << "1. " << breadPS << endl;
        cout << "2. " << vICS << endl;
        cout << "3. " << sjGS << endl;
        cout << "4. " << gelatoS << endl;
        cout << "5. " << butterTS << endl;
        cout << "6. Back" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> dessertInput;
        } while ((dessertInput!="1")&&(dessertInput!="2")&&(dessertInput!="3")&&(dessertInput!="4")&&(dessertInput!="5")&&(dessertInput!="6"));
}
void attSelection ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "-= WHAT KIND =-" << endl;
        cout << "1. " << beef << endl;
        cout << "2. " << pork << endl;
        cout << "3. " << chicken << endl;
        cout << "4. " << shrimp << endl;
        cout << "5. " << tofu << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> attInput;
    } while ((attInput!="1")&&(attInput!="2")&&(attInput!="3")&&(attInput!="4")&&(attInput!="5"));
}
void addAnother ()
{
    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Add another item from the same category? (1 for YES, 2 for NO): ";
        cin >> addAnotherInput;
    } while ((addAnotherInput!="1")&&(addAnotherInput!="2"));
}

int main ()
{
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << setprecision(2);
    mainLoop:
    tableSelection ();
    // IF TABLE 1 START
    if (tableNumber==table1)
    {
        vector<string> tableOneList;
        vector<float> tableOnePriceList;

        tableOneLoop:
        cout << string(50, '\n');
        cout << "-= TABLE 1 =-" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        menuSelection ();
        // IF VIEW TOTAL START
        if (selectInput=="8")
        {
            cout << endl;
            for(vector<string>::const_iterator items = tableOneList.begin(); items != tableOneList.end(); ++items )
            for(vector<float>::const_iterator prices = tableOnePriceList.begin(); prices!= tableOnePriceList.end(); ++prices)
            cout << *items << endl;
            cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;
            cout << "TOTAL: " << "$" << sum(tableOnePriceList) << endl;
            totalpreTax=sum(tableOnePriceList);
            cout << "HST:   " << "$" << totalpreTax*addtaxHST << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "GRAND TOTAL: " << "$" << totalpreTax*totaltaxHST << endl;
        }
        // IF VIEW TOTAL END

        // IF APPY START
        if (selectInput=="1")
        {
            appyLoop:
            appySelection ();
            if (appyInput=="1")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(kimBabS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(kimBab);
                cout << endl;
                cout << kimBabS << " successfully added.";
                cout << endl;
                goto tableOneLoop;
            }
            if (appyInput=="2")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(jonS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(jon);
                cout << endl;
                cout << jonS << " successfully added.";
                cout << endl;
                addAnother ();
                if (addAnotherInput=="1")
                {
                    goto appyLoop;
                }
                if (addAnotherInput=="2")
                {
                    goto tableOneLoop;
                }
            }
            if (appyInput=="3")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(kJonS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(kJon);
            }
            if (appyInput=="4")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(sTofuS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(sTofu);
            }
            if (appyInput=="5")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(wanjaS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(wanja);
            }
            if (appyInput=="6")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(kgSaladS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(kgSalad);
            }
            if (appyInput=="7")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(edamameS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(edamame);
            }
            if (appyInput=="8")
            {
                tableOneList.push_back(kimBabS);
                tableOnePriceList.push_back(kimBab);
            }
        }
        // IF APPY END

        // IF MAIN START
        if (selectInput=="2")
        {
            mainSelection ();
        }
        // IF MAIN END

        // IF SOUP START
        if (selectInput=="3")
        {
            soupSelection ();
        }
        // IF SOUP END

        // IF RICENOODLE START
        if (selectInput=="4")
        {
            riceNoodleSelection ();
        }
        // IF RICENOODLE END

        // IF FUSION START
        if (selectInput=="5")
        {
            fusionSelection ();
        }
        // IF FUSION END

        // IF DESSERT START
        if (selectInput=="6")
        {
            dessertSelection ();
        }
        // IF DESSERT END

        // IF BACK START
        if (selectInput=="7")
        {
            goto mainLoop;
        }
        // IF BACK END
    }
}    // IF TABLE 1 END


float sum(const vector<float>& x) {
    float total = 0.0;  // the sum is accumulated here
    for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++) {
        total = total + x[i];  
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I worked at a place who's HP printer would do this. Instead of 5 copies it would print 25.

Comment: I dare to say I've never seen such a ratio of `numOfDeclaredVariables/linesOfCode`

Comment: You may wish to consider the architecture of your code.

Comment: Also don't use 'float' for currency calculations.  Use fixed point arithmetic.

Comment: And never use goto like this if at all#

Comment: This may be more appropriate on code review? Unless you narrow down the portion of your code causing the problem.

Comment: @Pete For *exceptions* in C, within a function, never out of one...

Comment: @WhozCraig: Seriously, that beats any record :D

Comment: @Eterm: No -- code review is for review of *working* code.

Comment: I hope your parents never change their menu!

Comment: Go easy on the OP. They're obviously quite meticulous, and organised, but haven't learned about data structures to allow data driven code.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, as I mentioned, I'm only a lowly beginner CS student, who is doing this for practice. I think I received some really incredible feedback to start improving.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain why is it tagged C++ then? - he should use _exceptions_ for exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would find it difficult to fix this in its current form.

I would start changing it by getting rid of duplication.

You have lots of variables where the name, the content, the price are kept separately. The number to select them, etc.

You need to introduce a few key data structures. I'm not going to do the whole thing for you.

```
struct Price {
    const unsigned int pennies;
    Price(int pennies);
};

struct Dish {
    const string name;
    const Price price;
    Dish(string name, Price price);
};

struct SubMenu {
    const string name;
    const vector<Dish> dishes;
    SubMenu(string name, vector<Dish> dishes);
};

typedef vector<SubMenu> Menu;

Menu menu;
menu.push_back(
    SubMenu("appetizers", {
        Dish("KIMBAB", Price(550)),
        Dish("JON", Price(750))
        })); // etc
```

Then you can say, for example:

```
SubMenu& subMenu = menu[0];

cout << subMenu.name << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < subMenu.dishes.size(); ++i) {
    cout << i << " " << subMenu.dishes[i] << endl;
}
```

You should be able to have one function to print any submenu.

Additionally, read in the choice into an integer and just check the range:

```
do {
    unsigned int choice;
    cin >> choice;
} while(choice >= subMenu.dishes.size());
```

These few changes will vastly reduce the size of your code, and increase its readability, and your ability to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your double for loop under if(selectInput == "8"). This squares the number of outputs. The second for loop (the price loop) is completely unused, and should be removed. Prevent this problem in the future by using parenthesis and proper indentation, even for one line loops.

And please, PLEASE, use arrays, don't use strings if you don't actually want to store text, and avoid gotos.

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort to provide an answer, and for the array suggestion! His code is *way* longer than it needs to be.

Comment: OP here. I would like to take the time to thank anyone who went through the absolute shitstorm of a code I have here.

As an intro student, I've just been trying to just learn and improve by practice and applications of the things I have learned.

I will study structures and arrays more.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

Being a beginner CS student I would recommend trying something like the following for your data to start:

```
struct menuItem
{
    menuItem(string name, MenuTypes type, float price)
    { 
        this.name=name;
        this.type=type; 
        this.price=price;
    }
    string name;
    MenuTypes type;
    float price;
};

enum MenuTypes
{
    Appetizer,
    Main,
    Soup,
    Rice_And_Noodles,
    Fusion,
    Dessert
}
```

Then you can just create a list of menu items using STL List or you could even create an array like such:

```
menuItem myMenu[20]; //or whatever # of items you expect in your menu
int curItem = 0;
myMenu[curItem++] = new menuItem("firstItemName", MenuTypes.Appetizer, 1.34f);
myMenu[curItem++] = new menuItem("secondItemName", MenuTypes.Appetizer, 2.35f);
...
```

Just make sure you create a large enough array btw if you do this....this will definately make things a lot easier... this way you can create a menu like so:

```
int displayMenu(MenuTypes theType){
    int curMenuCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myMenu.size(); i++){
         if(myMenu[i].type == theType){
              cout << ++curMenuCount << myMenu[i].name << endl;
         }
    }
    return curMenuCount;
}
```

then to find the item:

```
float getPriceForItem(int selection, MenuType theType){
    int curNumForThisMenu = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myMenu.size(); i++){
        if(myMenu[i].type == theType) curNumForThisMenu++;
        if(curNumForThisMenu == selection){
            return myMenu[i].price;
        }
    }
}
```

something like this would make your code a lot easier to read without getting too advanced (hopefully) for your level. Of course there's better ways to do this, but this is probably a good start for you.